# please tell Time complexity of following program

Tags: time-complexity

[image]
please tell the time complexitiy of the following code

Comment: It's the time of the year to consider consequences of *not* doing assignments yourself, let alone dumping them on others, not even investing the effort to type them.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\mathcal{O}(y + n^{2})$, as the first loop does $\mathcal{O}(n)$ operations and increments $y$ by $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \mathcal{O}(n^{2})$, and the second loop does $\mathcal{O}(y')$ operations, where $y' = y + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is the modified value of $y$.